# Mean and variance of conditional distribution of truncated normal distribution

Tags: distributions, conditional-expectation, truncated-normal-distribution

Let's say that I have

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} 
\sim N
\begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} \hat{x} \\ \hat{y} \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix} A & C \\ C^{T} & B \end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with $x >= 0$

So that x is truncated normal, and y is simply normal

Given the means and variances of the unconditional distribution (above), is it possible to write down the distribution for $x | y$?

Comment: are you asking $p(X|Y=y,X\geq 0)$? Because x cannot be truncated normal and at the same time jointly normal.

Comment: I guess for the sake of argument, you could think of x and y being jointly truncated multivariate normal, but with the bounds of Y being -Inf and Inf

Comment: Then, what does the joint distribution formula will look like? Maybe add some clarification to the question.

Comment: @gunes I'm not sure, to be honest. This paper https://surface.syr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1149&context=ecn has some results, but it doesn't frame the conditional distributions in terms of their means and variances

Comment: This is simpler than it might look: the conditional distributions of $x$ are Normal, so you thereby obtain truncated Normal distributions.